How to aggregate for first values in group
I have troubles creating certain aggregations. I'm using this table in  Postgres:
CREATE TABLE public.courier (
sender_app_type character varying(255),
customer_id integer,
from_id integer,
to_id integer,
chat_started_by_message boolean,
order_id integer,
order_stage character varying(255),
courier_id integer,
message_sent_time timestamp with time zone
);

Some sample rows:
INSERT INTO public.courier(
    sender_app_type, customer_id, from_id, to_id, chat_started_by_message, order_id, order_stage, courier_id, message_sent_time)
VALUES  ('IOS',99,99,21,FALSE,555,'UP',21,timestamp '9/8/22 8:02'),
        ('Courier IOS',99,21,99,FALSE,555,'ARR',21,timestamp '9/8/22 8:01'),
        ('IOS',99,99,21,FALSE,555,'UP',21,timestamp '9/8/22 8:00'),
        ('Android',122,87,122,TRUE,38,'ADDRESS_DELIVERY',87,timestamp '9/8/22 7:55'),
        (‘Android',43,43,75,FALSE,875,'UP',75,timestamp '7/8/22 14:55'),
        ('Android',43,75,43,FALSE,875,'ARR',75,timestamp '7/8/22 14:53'),
        ('Android',43,43,75,FALSE,875,'UP',75,timestamp '7/8/22 14:51'),
        ('Android',43,75,43,TRUE,875,'ADD',75,timestamp '7/8/22 14:50'),
        ('IOS',23,23,21,FALSE,134,'UP',21,timestamp '7/8/22 10:02'),
        ('IOS',23,21,23,FALSE,134,'ARr',21,timestamp '7/8/22 10:01'),
        ('my IOS',23,23,21,FALSE,134,'UP',21,timestamp '7/8/22 10:00');

I need build that aggregates individual messages into conversations. The query result should be used to create a table customer_courier_conversations (take into consideration that a conversation is unique per order).
a. The required fields are the following:

first_courier_message: Timestamp of the first courier message
first_customer_message: Timestamp of the first customer message
num_messages_courier: Number of messages sent by courier
num_messages_customer: Number of messages sent by customer
first_message_by: The first message sender (courier or customer)
conversation_started_at: Timestamp of the first message in the conversation

This is what I have so far:
SELECT  ccc.order_id, 
    ord.city_code,
    string_agg(ccc.message_sent_time::character varying, ',' order by ccc.courier_id desc) as first_courier_message,
    string_agg(ccc.message_sent_time::character varying, ',' order by ccc.customer_id asc) as first_customer_message,
    count(ccc.courier_id) as num_messages_courier,  
    count(ccc.customer_id) as num_messages_customer,
    string_agg(ccc.sender_app_type,' ' order by )
FROM courier ccc
INNER JOIN "Orders" ord
  ON ccc.order_id = ord.order_id
group by ccc.order_id, ord.city_code;

Am I going in the right direction?
And how do I implement the last two items?

Are you series about Postgres 9.5? This ancient version has been unsupported since 2021.

Do you mean something like this?
WITH first_msg_by(first_msg_by) AS (
  SELECT SPLIT_PART(sender_app_type,' ',1)
  FROM public.customer_courier_chat_messages
  ORDER BY message_sent_time
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT
  MIN  (CASE WHEN SPLIT_PART(sender_app_type,' ',1)='Courier'  THEN message_sent_time END) AS first_courier_msg
, MIN  (CASE WHEN SPLIT_PART(sender_app_type,' ',1)='Customer' THEN message_sent_time END) AS first_cust_msg
, COUNT(CASE WHEN SPLIT_PART(sender_app_type,' ',1)='Courier'  THEN message_sent_time END) AS count_courier_msg
, COUNT(CASE WHEN SPLIT_PART(sender_app_type,' ',1)='Customer' THEN message_sent_time END) AS count_cust_msg
, MIN(first_msg_by)                                                                        AS first_msg_by
, MIN(message_sent_time)                                                                   AS conv_started_at
FROM public.customer_courier_chat_messages CROSS JOIN first_msg_by;




first_courier_msg
first_cust_msg
count_courier_msg
count_cust_msg
first_msg_by
conv_started_at




2022-07-08 10:01:00
2022-07-08 10:00:00
5
6
Customer
2022-07-08 10:00:00




the result for this query will show us the unique row for the customer. i modify the question. The idea is get agregated row based on Orders

you need to use the window function: first_value() and last_value()
so in your case:
select ....
FIRST_VALUE(ccc.courier_id) OVER( ORDER BY ccc.message_sent_time) as first_courier_message,
FIRST_VALUE(ccc.customer_id) OVER( ORDER BY ccc.message_sent_time) as first_customer_message,
...

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-first_value-function/
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html

the problem here is we have to set inside the group by , the columns ccc.courier_id, ccc.customer_id, ccc.message_sent_time and that will show us several rows. i update the question, the idea is get an agregation query per ORDER.

You can't mix these window functions with aggregate functions freely. If you just add these lines, you get a error messages.

SELECT *
     , CASE COALESCE(first_msg_courier , 'infinity')
          < COALESCE(first_msg_customer, 'infinity')
          WHEN true  THEN 'Courier'
          WHEN false THEN 'Customer'  -- ELSE null
       END AS first_msg_by
     , LEAST(first_msg_courier, first_msg_customer) AS conversation_start
FROM  (
   SELECT order_id
        , min(message_sent_time) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Co') AS first_msg_courier
        , min(message_sent_time) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Cu') AS first_msg_customer
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Co') AS num_msg_courier
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Cu') AS num_msg_customer        
   FROM  (SELECT order_id, left(sender_app_type, 2) AS app_type, message_sent_time FROM customer_courier_chat_messages) c
   GROUP  BY order_id
   ) sub;

fiddle
The aggregate FILTER clause was added with Postgres 9.4, so this works even with your museum piece. See:

Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters

